# Limits preserve cross product

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are sequences of vectors that converge to $a$ and $b$, respectively. Can we say that the sequence $\{a_n \times b_n\}$ converges to $a \times b$?

This seems like it should hold, but I cannot figure out the arithmetic associated with proving it. Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @guy3141 Converging magnitudes does not mean converging vectors. E.g. take $\mathbb R^2 \ni a_n = (\cos n, \sin n)$. Then $|a_n| = 1$, yet the sequence never converges (in fact, it is dense in the unit circle).

Comment: @ lisyarus yes of course, my mistake.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because taking the cross product is just a linear transformation : 
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0&-a_3&a_2 \\ a_3&0&-a_1 \\ -a_2&a_1&0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix}$$
which is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

To prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\times b_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\times\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$, verify the $i$th component:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n\times b_n)_i=\epsilon_{ijk}\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)_j(b_n)_k=\epsilon_{ijk}\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)_j\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n)_k=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\times\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\right)_i.$$

Answer (score 0):

$a_{n}\times b_{n}=(a_{2,n}b_{3,n}-a_{3,n}b_{2,n})i+\cdots\rightarrow(a_{2}b_{3}-a_{3}b_{2})i+\cdots=a\times b$, where $a_{n}=(a_{1,n},a_{2,n},a_{3,n})$ and so on.